# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento2. there is showing an error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". How I can fix this please help.
please check the screen short of error :- http://prntscr.com/k48rpk

Comment: are trying to delete the foreign key from the field?

Comment: No I am not trying to to delete foreign .

Comment: first of all truncate the table on which you applied the foreign key,then ALTER table.it will work.